# Where can I find System.Web.MVC dll in a system where MVC 3 is installed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to know where I can find the `System.Web.MVC` dll in a system, where MVC 3 is already installed. I want to it on an X64-based system.

Any idea how to get them?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

the default folder would be like the following:

**MVC 5**

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Stack 5\Packages\ Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll*

**MVC 4**

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll*

**MVC 3**

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll*

**MVC 2**

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll*

Answer (score 17):

If you have found this question because you don't see `System.Web.MVC.dll` in .NET Framework Assemblies on your machine then you should install `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` NuGet package into your project. Then you will be able to `using System.Web.MVC;`

Default ASP.NET MVC Visual Studio project templates do exactly so and they don't use dll's from `Microsoft ASP.NET` folder on your machine.

Hope it will help somebody.