# How do I install MVC3 on a server without using the Web Platform Installer (and without Visual Studio)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, installation

How do I install MVC3 on a server without using the Web Platform Installer (and without Visual Studio)?

I can't seem to locate a standalone installer, and the server won't have VS, and I can't ensure that all the apps will have the binaries included to run it on native .NET4.

Is the only way to install MVC3 support with VS support, even if VS isn't around?

In case it isn't obvious, I'm trying to give the IT group a baseline of packages to install, and the easiest way to do that is to give them the binaries and a few scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing the link on http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3 we get a link to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491 | ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update

I think that's what you're looking for.

> ASP.NET MVC 3 is a framework for developing highly testable and maintainable Web applications by leveraging the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern. The framework encourages developers to maintain a clear separation of concerns among the responsibilities of the application – the UI logic using the view, user-input handling using the controller, and the domain logic using the model. ASP.NET MVC applications are easily testable using techniques such as test-driven development (TDD).
>   The installation package includes templates and tools for Visual Studio 2010 to increase productivity when writing ASP.NET MVC applications. For example, the Add View dialog box takes advantage of customizable code generation (T4) templates to generate a view based on a model object. The default project template allows the developer to automatically hook up a unit-test project that is associated with the ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: I looked at that before I posted this, but because of the text (which I'm going to edit your post with) I don't think this is the right one, but am open to being told it is indeed the one I want. **The installation package includes templates and tools for Visual Studio 2010 to increase productivity when writing ASP.NET MVC applications.**

Comment: By the exact same token there's: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4211 | ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM

Comment: Nah man, it says some parts of what are installed would need VS2010.  Doesn't mean you need it installed.  And example would be having an MVC 3 project available when adding a new project.  Those types of "features" would require VS2010.  Since you aren't using the server to develop on, who cares about those kinds of features?

Comment: So, have you installed with this installer yet?  It is the correct installer that you're looking for, I've used it on Server 2008 instances many times without Visual Studio installed.

Comment: I've got a test server later today waiting to be installed and I was going to test it then >.<

Comment: use bin deployment its much easier

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from : https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=4211

Is the 3.0.0.0 version and you can reference manually the DLL from : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll

Other versions : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485175/5775048

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the MVC3 runtime from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4211.
2. Go to c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework[64]\v4.0.30319 and run aspnet_regiis -i (adjusting for whatever version of .Net is appropriate).
3. Restart IIS.

This has always worked for me, although at the moment I'm having an issue because the installer installs 3.0.0.0 and my app is looking for 3.0.0.1.

Comment: That was a recent security patch from Microsoft. Ensure it gets delivered with the application at compile time.