# Can't find nuget package for system.web.mvc 3.0.0.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

Can't find nuget package for system.web.mvc 3.0.0.1

All I can find is this:
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 3.0.20105.1

Which installs 3.0.0.0 I want to deploy my ap to QA with the correct version for testing.

Where can I get the nugget package?

Comment: Or the just Dll and version remap file?

Comment: **Check the answer write below link** http://stackoverflow.com/a/26772349/5269727

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the next version of it, i.e.:

```
    Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 3.0.50813.1
```