# Visual Studio : The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

As said in the title, I got this message in the errors list, I've tried to réinstall the MVC package from nuget, it didn't work, I searched on google, and tried other solutions ...

What I have tried :

- reinstall MVC from nuget package manager
- re-create a new project
- clean and rebuild
- I checked the reference path from System.web.mvc, the file exists

Even on new project I have this error ...

Sorry for my bad english :(

I wish someone could finally solve my problem =(

Comment: you have some solution here. Click below link. May help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535131/system-web-mvc-missing

Comment: What is the name of the template when you create a new project? Which target framework are you selecting?

Comment: thanks @Pavan Chandaka, it worked :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26772349/3448308

It downgraded to older version and worked ...

Thanks to @Pavan Chandaka

EDIT: i had to downgrade to 5.2.0 to make it work again (it was 5.2.3 (last release))