# How build older version projects in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to compile this [old project(link to old project)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-the-DropDownList-67f9367d) But I am getting a lot of missing namespaces which cannot be resolved. Usually, when I open older projects I can resolve these by clicking the lightbulb and import correct namespace but there are none suggested.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Can you give an example of a missing namespace? Is this namespace related to your solution or part of .net?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'SelectListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Then Remove Unnecessary Using

Comment: So, did you google that specific error? Gives you a number of hints already.

Comment: Yes!, I have googled it and it says I need using System.Web.Mvc; But it is asking me to remove it (Then Remove Unnecessary Using)

Comment: @3spot answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535131/system-web-mvc-missing) helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make this work, you will need to follow these steps:

1. Go to the NuGet PackageManager, and add MVC from Microsoft

[image: MVC v5.2.3]

2. Change all ambiguous references from `Compare` to `System.Web.Mvc.Compare`.
3. Remove the following line from the Web.config in your project root:

   `<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>`
4. Change the following lines in the project Root Web.config:

   `<add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>`

   `<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>`

   `<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>`

To these values (Note the **Version** change):

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

5. Change the following lines in the project Root, *Views folder*, Web.config:

   `<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">`

   `<section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />`

   `<section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />`

To these values (Note the **Version** change):

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
```