# 'System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

The complete error is *"'System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'"*

I have an Asp.Net Mvc 4 application build in Visual Studio 2010 that does not build on one machine but builds on another machine without issue. Through the tips [System.web.mvc missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535131/system-web-mvc-missing/) I discoverd that the machine that builds does indeed have MVC 3 version 3.0.50813.0 and the machine that does not build has MVC 3 version 3.0.20105.0 so I uninstalled MVC 4 and MVC 3 and attempted every combination of uninstall and reinstall between downloaded installers and the web platform installer but the problem machine still gets the older version. I decide that I will just attempt to fix the project by upgrading the NuGet package for the one project using the suggestion from the question

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 3.0.50813.1
```

at which point it the following error with the NuGet package Manager
*"Install-Package : The schema version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc' is incompatible with version 2.0.30625.9003 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version"* In attempting to fix that I find this [Nuget versioning issue with package restore](http://Install-Package%20:%20The%20schema%20version%20of%20'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'%20is%20incompatible%20with%20version%202.0.30625.9003%20of%20NuGet.%20Please%20upgrade%20NuGet%20to%20the%20latest%20version%20from%20http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942./)
 I performed the answer from there and got the same error when attempting to install the NuGet package, which makes sense because it is looking for an older version of NuGet.

I also looked at this [MS14-059](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-ms14-059-broke-my-build/%22%22) but my project does not even reference the MVC 3 dll so the manual update option is out and I have tried the NuGet package.

My question is

1. Does anyone know where I can find an installation of the MVC 3 framework for version 3.0.50813.0

**OR**

2. How I can get the NuGet package to install in my solution.

Comment: this link maybe help you :
http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2007/12/system-web-mvc-controller-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced/

Comment: Thank you for the link but unfortunately I still have the issue.