# VisulaStudio 2013 not Accepect JsonResult while i take Empty WebApi

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

Here i'm using visualstudio2013 i select EmptyTemplate with WebApi why its not Accepecting JsonResult Like

```
Public JsonResult GetData(){
}
```

Here i'm Getting at JsonResult Not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're searching for is a part of the System.Web.Mvc.dll file. You have to add this reference to your project.

If you don't know how to add references, this should be very interesting for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

If you can't find this file on your system, this should be very interesting as well: [Where can I find System.Web.MVC dll in a system where MVC 3 is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485166/where-can-i-find-system-web-mvc-dll-in-a-system-where-mvc-3-is-installed)