# What is the difference between the these two FileStreamResult from different classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, filestreamresult

What is the difference between `System.Web.Mvc`'s `FileStreamResult` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`'s `FileStreamResult`? Is there any significant take away of using the latter over the first one?

**Edit:**

Is it possible to have `.Net Core` project but still use `System.Web.Mvc`? I don't know how but just asking for possibility here, is it or is not?

Comment: `is it or is not?` No, it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`System.Web.Mvc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc) namespace is used the .NET Framework. If your project is targetting the .NET Framework, use this.

The [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc) namespace is used in .NET Core. If your project is targetting .NET Core, use this.

Only one of them will be available to you, depending on your project.

You *can* have an ASP.NET Core project that [targets the full .NET Framework](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2018/03/31/running-aspnet-core-2-under-the-full-dotnet-framework/), and then add a reference to [`System.Web.Mvc.dll`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485175/1202807) directly. That *might* work. But I don't know why you would want to.

But if your ASP.NET Core project is targetting .NET Core, then there is no way to use `System.Web.Mvc`.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Web.Mvc` namespace is used by the .NET Framework MVC. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` is used by .NET Core MVC. Pick appropriatly for the type of project you are building.